# Not able to do simple twilio call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am not able to do simple 2 way audio call between 2 numbers using twilio.
I have attached my python (Django) code. when I run the code, call Get connected and but after accepting call it get's disconnected immediately. also, I am not able listen to anything on Laptop.

I have joined the code and twiml from twilio.

```
def call_m(request):
  account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
  auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'] 
  client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
  call = client.calls.create(
                        url='twiml_url',
                        to='+91985XXXXXXX',
                        from_='+132YYYYyYYY',
                    )
  print("sid ",call.sid)

return render(request, 'calls/incall.html')
```

Here's my twiml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response> 
</Response>
```

if i changed My twiml to this

```
<Response>
   <Dial>+9198xxxxxxxx</Dial>
</Response>
```

then after accepting call from "To" number, It say's number is busy please call later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have some misconceptions about how Twilio works when making calls.

When you generate a call with Twilio using the REST API that creates a call leg *between the `to` number and Twilio* (not between your laptop and the phone).

When that call is answered on the end of the `to` number, Twilio then makes an HTTP request to the `url` that you passed to the API. That URL should respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do with the call next.

Now, when your application responded with an empty TwiML response (`<Response></Response>`) that tells Twilio that there is nothing left to do in this call, so Twilio hangs up.

When your application responded with a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial), like this:

```xml
<Response>
   <Dial>+9198xxxxxxxx</Dial>
</Response>
```

my guess is that the number in the dial was the same number that you used in the `to` parameter to make the call. In this case, Twilio placed a call to your number in response to the REST API request and then placed another call to your number as directed by the TwiML `<Dial>` and that second call found that your number was busy because you are already on the line with Twilio.

If you used a different number in the `<Dial>` then Twilio would place a call to that number and when they answered the phone you would be connected to them.

If you want to connect two callers with their own phones, then using `<Dial>` like this is the way forward.

If you want to place a call from your laptop to another device, then you will need a bit more than just the REST API. In this instance you need to build an application using the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks) which allows you to make calls from a web browser or iOS or Android application. If this is of interest to you then I recommend you check out the [getting started guide for the JavaScript voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/get-started).

Answer (score 1):

The call needs TWiML to stay active, so that explains why it ends the call when you are returning an empty TwiML reponse. You must keep feeding it TwiML to keep the call up.

Specific to calling the number, there could be an issue dialing that number that Twilio support could investigate, if geographic permissions allow international calls to that destination.

Comment: Thank you @alan.
How can I Keep the TWiML active, just for normal call?

Geographic permission is allowed in settings.

Comment: Specific to the dial verb, that will keep the call up until the call is completed. Why the test dialed number is busy (I assume it is your number and not busy), Twilio support would need to investigate. Are you initially calling the same number via the REST api you are trying to dial once that party picks up and thus the busy? Also, note the callerID will be the number you dialed via the REST API and maybe the dialed destination  has issue with that callerID? Otherwise outside the dial verb, you can use the TwiML redirect verb to keep feeding Twilio new TwiML documents when needed.

Comment: I was calling the same number that's why I was getting busy tone.
thank you Alan.

Comment: Glad to help out, I've done that myself.